# ImageMagick 2 Versions

Tags: imagemagick

I had ImageMagick installed on my server.  I downloaded and installed a newer version, but installed it in the folder /usr/share/ImageMagick-6.8.9-10

The new version is installed, but when I run convert, it is referencing the old version.

Did I install it in the wrong location?  How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check out ["Hints and tips specific to Imagemagick"](http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/graphics/imagemagick.hints), a great little document on environment configuration.

In short, you'll need to set-up ENVIRONMENT variables to reference the new ImageMagick location.

*example*

```
export PATH=/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.8.9-10/bin:$PATH
# or 
export MAGICK_HOME=/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.8.9-10
```

You can add such entries to `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.profile` depending on system) to autoload environment settings on each login. If needed, daemon services will need to have there respected environment updated (example apache's [mod_env](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv))